# returning undefined for get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been doing a project in URL shortening and i am getting an undefined as a result to get request.
Also i get a blank page too as result,but according to my knowledge everything is ok,i can't figure out what is the mistake
Here's my code(**please check the app.get section**)

```
'use strict';
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var express = require('express');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var http = require("http");
var cors = require('cors');
const dns = require('dns'); 
  
var app = express();

// Basic Configuration 
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

/** this project needs a db !! **/ 
// mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI);

app.use(cors());

/** this project needs to parse POST bodies **/
// you should mount the body-parser here

app.use('/public', express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(process.cwd() + '/views/index.html');
});

  
// your first API endpoint... 
app.get("/api/hello", function (req, res) {
  res.json({greeting: 'hello API'});
});
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
var saveSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  url: Number,
 
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

/** 3) Create and Save a Person */
var SaveData = mongoose.model('Save', saveSchema);

//**Here's the start of my problem,i think**
app.get("/api/shorturl/:id1",function(req,res){
 SaveData.find({url:1},function(err,data){  console.log(data.name)//**i am getting undefined for this in console**
res.json(data.name);})
});
app.post("/api/shorturl/new",(req,res)=>{
var body=req.body.url;
dns.lookup(body,(err,data)=>{
  var new2= new SaveData({name:body,url:1});
new2.save((err,data)=>{res.json(new2);});
})
});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Node.js listening ...');
});
```

I checked my DB whether the schema data is inputted or not, it is getting inside DB, so retrieval makes the problem I think.

Comment: `SaveData.find({url:1})` will give you the resource with URL whose value is 1. Are you sure such type of resource exists? 
Do print err and data as well, and see what is the output. Either data is null or there is an error. If no matching document is found with the find filter, you will get null in data

Comment: What do you see when you do `console.log(data)` instead?

Comment: You can always do some debugging yourself first: 1) always look up the command you're using to see what it actually does. 2) `console.log` everything; double check that variables contain what you assume they contain. Logging `data` instead of `data.name` would've immediately solved this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mongoose.model.prototype.find` returns an **array** of objects found. If you type `Array.prototype.name` in a console somewhere, you'll get `undefined`. Instead, use `mongoose.model.prototype.findOne`.

Answer (score 0):

Your enviorment variables are working? I notice you're not using `dotenv` module or something like that to configure your `process.env`.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. (also without the mongodb connection working, the program would crash before even reacting to client-side requests)